# Informix top command?

Tags: sql-server, informix

Is there a top operator for informix like there is in SQL Server?

I want to run a delete that will just delete the top say 1000 records based on a ordered select.

e.g.

```
delete from table 
 where id in (select top 1000 id from table order by date desc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use the FIRST clause with the select statemen

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0984.htm

Comment: Thanks.  although it turns out i dont have an informix database.  It seems like i have a variant that doesn't have "FIRST".  Still, cheers mate!